# Drupal 7. in the views, making clickable and not clickable links of the same content type

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, clickable

A problem in Drupal 7.

there are two content types **Publications** and **Staff**.

Each **Publication** has multiple *authors* from the "**Staff**". The **Staff** has two kinds, *internal* Staff and *external* Staff.

In the view I show the **Publications** with their *authors* from the **Staff**, all the Staff members are clickable links. How can I make **only** the **internal Staff members** clickable  links and the others not clickable ie. not links.

I am using **Drupal 7**.

Comment: How are you theming the view? Are you outputting fields or full nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable writing code? You could remove the link from your **Staff** field. Then, in a preprocess function, loop over the result set and for any that are not *external*, convert the staff name to a link.